# sklearn.naive_bayes VS categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, python, scikit-learn

In a binary classification, how can I use sklearn.naive_bayes python module to predict the class of inputs with 5 categorical variables (not binary)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hot encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) the categorical variables and use Bernoulli naive Bayes. Hot encoding is usually the trick one uses in representing categorical variables.

Comment: Thanks @Emre for your quick answer. Yes I ended up by using sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer to Hot encode the categorical variables. What do you think ?

Comment: Sounds good, but [the documentation says](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) *All classifiers in scikit-learn do multiclass classification out-of-the-box*, so you should be able to let sklearn do the encoding. If it does not work for you let us know.

Comment: Yes I ended up by using sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer before using sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB and gave pretty nice results (not satisfied though) :)